# Is there any way to disable paging in comments when requesting statuses in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The graph path "Facebook_ID/statuses" will return a user's statuses with their comments and likes. As described in here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ref … pi/status/

However if there are more than 25 comments in the status, there will be some paging... Does anyone know how to disable the paging?

I'm not sure about the likes, but it might be the case that it might be paged as well...

BTW, I know that requesting "Facebook_ID/statuses&limit=9999" will disable paging for the number of statuses returned. I think there should be a way to do the same with comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this might be the luckiest day of my life. I just found out that I can do that by requesting:

"Facebook_ID/statuses&comments_limit=9999"

WIN! :)

Comment: But would you REALLY want to request 9999 comments at once? Sounds like a killer wait time.

Comment: You're commenting on a 3 year old answer; back then I was stupid.

Comment: Haha, sorry I couldn't resist.

Comment: So is there any way of remove paging? I want to load just 10 but it still shows paging after 10 pages..